# modelsim source code

Tags: verilog, modelsim

The following is some modelsim code:

```
 begin
    tb_in_top = 0;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b0000;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b0001;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b0010;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b0011;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b0100;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b0101;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b0110;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b0111;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b1000;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b1001;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b1010;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b1011;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b1100;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b1101;
    #5 tb_in_top = 4'b1110;#5 tb_in_top = 4'b1111;
    #100 $finish;
  end
```

What does the #5 and #100 represent? Are those line numbers? Is there something wrong with this code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not "ModelSim" code any more than something is "Visual Studio" code.  It's [Verilog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verilog).

The `#` token signifies a delay in nanoseconds.

So what this code means is:

- At t = 0, set tb_in_top to all 0's.
- At t = 5 ns, set tb_in_top to the 4-bit binary value 0000.
- At t = 10 ns, set tb_in_top to the 4-bit binary value 0001.
- At t = 15 ns, set tb_in_top to the 4-bit binary value 0010.
- At t = 20 ns, set tb_in_top to the 4-bit binary value 0011.

(... keep counting up, incrementing tb_in_top by 1 every 5 ns ...)

- At t = 80 ns, set tb_in_top to the 4-bit binary value 1111.
- At t = 180 ns, end the simulation.

Yes, Verilog has `for` loops, and yes, that should be one.

#### Addendum

The `for` loop would look like:

```
integer index;
reg [3:0] tb_in_top;
begin
    tb_in_top = 0;
    for(index = 0; index < 16; index = index + 1)
    begin
        #5 tb_in_top = tb_in_top + 4'h1;
    end
    #100 $finish;
end
```

Finally, note that Verilog that uses the `#` time-delay operation cannot be synthesized to logic; it can only be used for simulation.

Comment: It would loop 2^4 (16) times.  Note that your original source has two statements per line of text.

Comment: By looking at the `for` loop declaration: `for(index = 0; index < 16; index = index + 1)`.  It works just like C.